# Using JLabel for text on custom drawn component causes painting bug

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, graphics2d, repaint

My little project involves a diagram editing tool, in which different sized boxes can be linked together. The drawing requirement for this is complex to say the least. You see the idea is that one can zoom in/out as far as they like and create ever smaller/larger boxes. This is sort of like a Mandelbrot, but as a diagram tool. This is shown in the image below.

[image: Image of parent box along with 3 children]

These boxes have text in them and my overall aim was for this text to be centered in the absolute center of the box. The only simple way I know for text to both center and wrap is by using JLabels. But when I tried this I came across a strange bug. The labels with multiple lines were prone to "disalign" vertically every other time they were repainted. (Sometimes this happened, other times it didn't. It has some consistency in that it keeps its behaviour when I replicate the same movement and positioning). This bug is shown in the image below.

[image: Image of parent box with one child with disaligned text]

Depending on the position, it would effectively alternate between the two images above. I have isolated the drawing of each box and ensured there was no escaping graphics transformations, and it seems this problem is down to the label painting.

I am aware that the practices I've used may not be preferable (e.g. painting JLabel directly), however I struggle to find any decent alternatives. If you guys can come up with a good alternative to using JLabels for centering and word wrap I'm happy to try it. Any ideas are welcome really.

Below is the drawing code for a **Box**. The colors are temporary.

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g, Map map, int fillAlpha, int lineAlpha, double zoom)
{
    if(this == map.selectedBox)
    {
        if(this == map.highlightedBox)
            g.setColor(new Color(200,235,235,fillAlpha));
        else
            g.setColor(new Color(200,225,225,fillAlpha));
    }
    else
    {
        if(this == map.highlightedBox)
            g.setColor(new Color(235,235,200,fillAlpha));
        else
            g.setColor(new Color(225,225,200,fillAlpha));
    }
    g.fill(rect);

    if(this == map.selectedBox)
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,255,lineAlpha));
    else
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,lineAlpha));
    g.draw(rect);

    g.translate(rect.x, rect.y);
    label.setForeground(g.getColor());
    label.paint(g);
    g.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);
}
```

Below is the drawing code for the **whole diagram**.

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g, int layer, Color aboveColor)
{
    for(Link link : linksObj(layer))
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        link.draw(g, this, aboveColor);
    }

    AffineTransform at = g.getTransform();
    g.scale(getZoom(layer), getZoom(layer));

    double ratio = getRatio(layer);

    int fill = getAnimAlpha(255, 0, ratio);
    int line = getAnimAlpha(255, 32, ratio);

    for(Box box : boxesObj(layer))
        box.draw(g, this, fill, line, getZoom(layer));
    g.setTransform(at);
}
```

The label uses the following to **center the text**.

```
public String convertForLabel(String in)
{
    return "<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">"+in.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")+"</html>";
}
```

**Edit:** I have created a test project for you to see the problem yourself. It is only one class so I just uploaded that. You can find it here: [JLabel Bug Class](http://www.sendspace.com/file/6n21io)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: You would be better off defining the Rectangle, Color, and String in a model class.  To draw a String, use the Graphics drawString method.  Here's a method that allows you to [center text in a rectangle](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=602).  You'll have to modify it some to draw multiple lines.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear but they are in a model class. The Box's drawing code is in the Box class. I thought about drawString but I need to achieve word wrap with variable-length (changable font) characters within the rectangle, this complicates things a lot.

Comment: FYI: I have added an MCVE, it is a single runnable class that demonstrates the problem I'm having.